# Custom CheckBoxList WebControl Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, checkboxlist, asp.net-webcontrol

I am creating a custom CheckBox WebControl which inherits From System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox in ASP.NET. But getting this error when postback:

*Input string was not in a correct format.*

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +10896279
System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +145
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +140
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +16
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +734
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1960
```

**I have a List of CheckBox which is called ItemList and OnInit I execute this function:**

```
 internal void InitItems()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox()
            {
                LabelPosition = CheckBox.LabelPositions.None
            };

            ItemList.Add(cb);
            Controls.Add(cb);
        }
    }
```

**And I call this method OnRender:**

```
public string RenderItems() { 

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ListItem item = this.Items[i];
            CheckBox cb = ItemList[i];
            cb.Text = item.Text;
            cb.Enabled = Enabled ? item.Enabled : Enabled;
            cb.Checked = item.Selected;
            cb.ID =  i.ToString();
            cb.ViewType = (CheckBox.ViewTypes) Enum.Parse(typeof(CheckBox.ViewTypes),this.ViewType.ToString());
            cb.DisplayType = (CheckBox.DisplayTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(CheckBox.DisplayTypes), this.DisplayType.ToString());
            if (this.AutoPostBack)
                cb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\\'" + cb.ClientName + "\\',\\'\\')', 0)");

            sb.Append(cb.GetHtml());
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I guess I am getting this error because generated checkboxes hava a *wrong ID or name*. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The only possibly reason that comes to my mind is this line:

```
cb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\\'" + cb.ClientName + "\\',\\'\\')', 0)");
```

you dont need those `\\`

```
cb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack('" + cb.ClientName + "','')', 0)");
```